# (FB Instant games) How I can get payload data from Game Play Button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-instant-games

According to this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/game-play/ I can post parameter "payload" for button with "SERIALIZED_JSON_PAYLOAD" and "this data will be sent to the game". How I can receive this data inside my game?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons#game_play mentions a Game Play webhook event, but the link behind that leads nowhere currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getEntryPointData` inside the game in order to access the payload. Note that it must be valid JSON for this to work.